# PHP file_get_contents() failed to open stream error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to the Amazon Flexible Payments sandbox, and I made a request string as they instruct in their documentation.  Now I am trying to send a request to their service by using the file_get_contents() PHP function, but I get this error:

```
[<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n in file_name.php on line 84
```

Any idea why that might happen?

Here is the URL I am sending:

```
https://authorize.payments-sandbox.amazon.com/cobranded-ui/actions/start?SignatureVersion=2&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.problemio.com%2Fproject.php%3Fproject_id%2FProject_name%3 &paymentReason=donation&callerReference=YourCallerReference&callerKey=not_shown&transactionAmount=4.0&pipelineName=SingleUse&Signature=not_shown_in_SO%3D%3D
```

Comment: Can you open any other URL using the same method ?

Comment: @pritaeas good point. I can open other urls. By open, it means download their output I guess since in my logs I get the output of the page I try to visit. So maybe I need a different function that actually takes the browser to the new page.

Comment: what if you just copy & paste this URL into your browser? Do you get a `404` too?

Comment: There is a warning in the PHP manual about SSL on IIS, not sure if that is applicable. Also, I am not sure how file_get_contents handles redirects. With cUrl you can set the option to follow them. @Jakub, if I do that on Opera it returns a 200 page, with a warning in HTML.

Comment: @Jakub if I paste it into the browser, i get a diff error: Caller Input Exception: Return Url is Malformed

Comment: you have more spaces `…Project_name%3 &paymentReason…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've left a space in your URL which breaks it:

```
.../start?SignatureVersion=2 &returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.problemio.c...
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got spaces in it: `…SignatureVersion=2 &returnUrl=…` and `…Project_name%3 &paymentReason…`